# Alternative to Easybcd

Tags: dual-boot, windows, easybcd

Recently installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10. Both OS work fine but I am unable to update the boot order via EasyBCD as Windows policy is not allowing add entry in EasyBCD. please share the alternative for EasyBCD available.

Comment: Ubuntu uses *GNU Grub* as its default boot-loader, which allows you to select which OS boots in dual boot environments, why not just use that?